# Class function not printing out data in php with mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, function, oop, mysqli

I need some help on a function that is not echoing the *$bonusjson* array. The function is *CheckBonus()*. All of the other functions work fine, except this one. When it's ran it echos nothing and I cannot figure out why. This is really my first time working with classes and functions. The *CheckBonus()* is suppose to query the database and check the table to see if the *$hash* variable data exists, then run the query and print out the data.

I think the issue is with *if($stmt->num_rows != 0)*. I have also tried using *if(!empty($stmt->store_result()))* instead and that prints the data, but if I change the *$hash* to something that is not in the database, it does not run *AddUser()*.

```
<?

//Mysql connect info
$servername = "removed";
$username = "removed";
$password = "removed";
$database = "removed";

$link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if ($link->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
}

//Get or send the information from/to the game
$func = $_GET['func'];
$hash = $link->real_escape_string($_GET['user']);
$bonus = $link->real_escape_string($_GET['bonus']);

class CheckUser
{
    function CheckBonus($hash)
    {
        global $link;
        global $hash;
        $query = "SELECT bonustier, resettime, userid FROM members WHERE userid = ?";
        if ($stmt = $link->prepare($query))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $hash);
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->num_rows != 0) {
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result($bonustier, $resettime, $hash);

                while($stmt->fetch())
                {
                    //Check if enough time has passed since last login bonus
                    $time = time();
                    $time2 = ((($time - $resettime) / 60) / 60);
                    $time3 = substr($time2, 0, strpos($time2, "."));

                    if($time3 >= 24)
                    {
                        $connection = 1;
                        $usergood = 1;
                        $loginbonus = 1;
                        $hoursince = $time3;

                        $bonusarray = array(
                            'BonusCheck' => array(
                                'connection' => $connection,
                                'usergood' => $usergood,
                                'loginbonus' => $loginbonus,
                                'bonustier' => $bonustier,
                                'hoursince' => $time3
                                ),
                            );

                        $bonusjson = json_encode($bonusarray, 128);
                        echo $bonusjson;
                    }
                    else //If enough time has not passed, tell the game.
                    {
                        $connection = 1;
                        $usergood = 1;
                        $loginbonus = 0;
                        $hoursince = $time3;

                        $bonusarray = array(
                            'BonusCheck' => array(
                                'connection' => $connection,
                                'usergood' => $usergood,
                                'loginbonus' => $loginbonus,
                                'bonustier' => $bonustier,
                                'hoursince' => $time3
                                ),
                            );

                        $bonusjson = json_encode($bonusarray, 128);
                        echo $bonusjson;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->AddUser($hash);
            }

        }
        $stmt->close();
    }

    function UpdateBonus($hash, $bonus)
    {
        global $link;
        global $hash;
        global $bonus;
        if($stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE members SET loginbonus = ?, bonustier = ?, resettime = ? WHERE userid=?"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $loginbonus, $bonustier, $resettime, $hash);

            switch($bonus)
            {
                case 0:
                    $bonustier = 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $bonustier = 2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $bonustier = 3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $bonustier = 4;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $bonustier = 5;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $bonustier = 0;
                    break;
            }

            $loginbonus = 0;
            $resettime = time();
            $success = '1';

            $updatearray = array(
                'UpdateBonus' => array(
                    'login' => $loginbonus,
                    'result' => $success
                    ),
                );

            $updatejson = json_encode($updatearray, 128);
            echo $updatejson;

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }

    function AddUser($hash)
    {
        global $link;
        global $hash;
        if($stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO members (userid, loginbonus, bonustier, resettime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $userid, $loginbonus, $bonustier, $resettime);

            $userid = $hash;
            $loginbonus = 1;
            $bonustier = 1;
            $resettime = time();

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            $this->CheckBonus($hash);
        }
    }

    function CheckFunc($func)
    {
        switch($func)
        {
            case cb:
                $this->CheckBonus($hash);
                break;
            case ub:
                $this->UpdateBonus($hash, $bonus);
                break;
            case au:
                $this->AddUser($hash);
                break;
            default:
                echo 'Function not found.';
                break;
        }
    }
}

$newObject = new CheckUser();
$newObject->CheckFunc($func);

?>
```

If you happen to downvote my quiestion, could you let me know why? What am I doing wrong here, what could I do better and what could I work more on when asking a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured out what I had done wrong. It seems to work as intended now. I moved *$stmt->store_result();* above the *if($stmt->num_rows != 0)* line and I changed that line to *if($stmt->num_rows > 0)*. Not sure if the second change actually had any effect, but it seemed better to use > over != in the statement.

Here is the code in a working state.

```
//Mysql connect info
$servername = "removed";
$username = "removed";
$password = "removed";
$database = "removed";

$link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if ($link->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
}

//Get or send the information from/to the game
$func = $_GET['func'];
$hash = $link->real_escape_string($_GET['user']);
$bonus = $link->real_escape_string($_GET['bonus']);

class CheckUser
{
    function CheckBonus($hash)
    {
        global $link;
        global $hash;
        $query = "SELECT bonustier, resettime, userid FROM members WHERE userid = ?";

        if ($stmt = $link->prepare($query))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $hash);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
            {
                $stmt->bind_result($bonustier, $resettime, $hash);

                while($stmt->fetch())
                {
                    //Check if enough time has passed since last login bonus
                    $time = time();
                    $time2 = ((($time - $resettime) / 60) / 60);
                    $time3 = substr($time2, 0, strpos($time2, "."));

                    if($time3 >= 24)
                    {
                        $connection = 1;
                        $usergood = 1;
                        $loginbonus = 1;
                        $hoursince = $time3;

                        $bonusarray = array(
                            'BonusCheck' => array(
                                'connection' => $connection,
                                'usergood' => $usergood,
                                'loginbonus' => $loginbonus,
                                'bonustier' => $bonustier,
                                'hoursince' => $time3
                                ),
                            );

                        $bonusjson = json_encode($bonusarray, 128);
                        echo $bonusjson;
                    }
                    else //If enough time has not passed, tell the game.
                    {
                        $connection = 1;
                        $usergood = 1;
                        $loginbonus = 0;
                        $hoursince = $time3;

                        $bonusarray = array(
                            'BonusCheck' => array(
                                'connection' => $connection,
                                'usergood' => $usergood,
                                'loginbonus' => $loginbonus,
                                'bonustier' => $bonustier,
                                'hoursince' => $time3
                                ),
                            );

                        $bonusjson = json_encode($bonusarray, 128);
                        echo $bonusjson;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->AddUser($hash);
            }

        }
        $stmt->close();
    }

    function UpdateBonus($hash, $bonus)
    {
        global $link;
        global $hash;
        global $bonus;

        if($stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE members SET loginbonus = ?, bonustier = ?, resettime = ? WHERE userid=?"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $loginbonus, $bonustier, $resettime, $hash);

            switch($bonus)
            {
                case 0:
                    $bonustier = 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $bonustier = 2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $bonustier = 3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $bonustier = 4;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $bonustier = 5;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $bonustier = 0;
                    break;
            }

            $loginbonus = 0;
            $resettime = time();
            $success = '1';

            $updatearray = array(
                'UpdateBonus' => array(
                    'login' => $loginbonus,
                    'result' => $success
                    ),
                );

            $updatejson = json_encode($updatearray, 128);
            echo $updatejson;

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }

    function AddUser($hash)
    {
        global $link;
        global $hash;

        if($stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO members (userid, loginbonus, bonustier, resettime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $userid, $loginbonus, $bonustier, $resettime);

            $userid = $hash;
            $loginbonus = 1;
            $bonustier = 1;
            $resettime = time();

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            $this->CheckBonus($hash);
        }
    }

    function CheckFunc($func)
    {
        switch($func)
        {
            case cb:
                $this->CheckBonus($hash);
                break;
            case ub:
                $this->UpdateBonus($hash, $bonus);
                break;
            case au:
                $this->AddUser($hash);
                break;
            default:
                echo 'Function not found.';
                break;
        }
    }
}

$newObject = new CheckUser();
$newObject->CheckFunc($func);

?>
```

If anyone happens to see something that is wrong or could be done better, please let me know. And yeah, I know I really should switch to using PDO. I just started learning classes a functions so I feel I need to work on this first, then start learning PDO.